# Explanation of some physical terms related to hydodynamic limit to a non-physicist & Integrable system

Tags: fluid-dynamics, terminology, definition, chirality, integrable-systems

I'm a mathematician, and I'm reading an article and am struggling with some of the terminology
related to physics.

> [...] This equation is formally obtained from the **hydrodynamic limit** of the
> Hamiltonian system of Calogero-Sutherland, describing the motion of particles on
> a circle of radius L, interacting according to a potential at $1/sin^2 x$.

what does hydrodynamic limit mean?

> [...] A change of variable of **Madelung type** leads to equation (0.1),

What does  a change of variable of  Madelung type mean?

And,

> the constraint u correspond to a **condition of chirality**.

What does mean: a condition of chirality?

Finaly, I have another question that isn't related to termenology.
Does the limit of an integrable system is an integrable system?

I'm asking this question here because at the begining of the article, I have an equation that is obtain as a hydrodynamic limit of the system of Calogero-Sutherland. And we know that the system of Calogero-Sutherland is completly integrable. So my question does the new equation is an integrable equation just because it's the limit of an integrable equation?

Comment: Reading which article?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.5327 Abanov, Bettelheim, Wiegmann. It's not exaclty this article, but it's based on it.